# How do i run symfonys tests?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm in need of some support. :)

I cloned the symfony/symfony repo, ran `composer update` and i get this when trying to run the tests:

```
[emil:~/Development/symfony](2.8) $ php ./phpunit symfony

Warning: require(/Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/phpunit on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/phpunit on line 4
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/phpunit on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/emil/Development/symfony/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/phpunit on line 4
KO src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine
```

My php version:

```
[emil:~/Development/symfony](2.8) $ php -v
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2015 23:48:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I'm on OS X 10.11.1. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The only thing i have done so far is cloning the repo and following this guide: https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/tests.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was caused by a bug.

My composer was installed in a bash-wrapper. The phpunit script tried to execute phpunit with php.

This PR should have fixed it.

A manual fix is to download composer.phar and place it in the .phpunit/phpunit-4.8 directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist`

Within your `phpunit.xml.dist` define the paths to your bootstrap.php and test sources (with adjusted paths):

```
<testsuites>
 <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
  <directory>vendor/symfony/symfony/src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
  <directory>vendor/symfony/symfony/src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```